# How to create oracle procedure to export data into history tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In an Oracle database, we have created 22 materialized views and we have created a procedure to refresh all these MV's. All 22 materialized views refresh successfully.

On the last day of every month, we wanted to refresh the materialized views and copy the data to historical tables.  These historical tables have the same structure along with three additional columns that contain the date the data was copied along with the month and year that the data represents.

- `copy_date` will be the `sysdate` when the data is copied to history table
- `month` and `year` will be passed in to the stored procedure.

For example, if I forgot to refresh at the end of January and remembered on February 4

- `copy_date`: 4th of feb
- 'month' and 'year' are : FEB and 2012

The reporting team will use these columns to filter the data in order to analyze it.

example : Table A

```
study country state
abc    india    ap
bcd    china    xx
```

I need a procedure that copies the data to a history table like:

```
month year copy_date     study  country state
jan   2013 01-01-2013    abc    india   ap
```

When I run this procedure, I want to enter values for the `month` and `year` parameters (jan and 2013 in this case).

Comment: What have you tried? You are asking others do the job for you. Post some working code and then you will get some help using that code as start. Check  this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on how to write and ask a good question.

Comment: Why would you want the procedure to create the table?  Presumably, there will be exactly one history table per materialized view.  That history table will be created once by a single script.  The procedure that you run monthly would then simply copy the data from the materialized view into the existing history table.

Comment: @Justin: Yes, history table is created. but i need procedure to copy data from main to history table as explained above. please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'm not sure why you would bother passing in the `month` and `year` parameters rather than simply deriving that from the `sysdate`.  In your example, you the `month` and `year` are based on the current `sysdate` whether you copy the data on January 30 or February 4.

One option would be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE copy_a( p_month IN VARCHAR2, p_year IN NUMBER )
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO a_history( month, year, copy_date, study, country, state )
    SELECT p_month, p_year, sysdate, study, country, state
      FROM a;
END;
```

You could also use dynamic SQL to avoid having to create 22 separate stored procedures.  If the history tables always have the `month`, `year`, and `copy_date` as their first three columns and have the remaining columns in exactly the same order as the base table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE copy_table( p_table_name IN VARCHAR2, 
                                        p_month IN VARCHAR2, 
                                        p_year IN NUMBER )
AS
  l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(10000);
BEGIN
  l_sql_stmt := 'INSERT INTO ' || p_table_name || '_hist ' ||
                ' SELECT :mnth, :yr, sysdate, a.* ' ||
                '   FROM ' || p_table_name;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt 
    USING p_month, p_year;
END;
```